# How to return to the calling method after calling a windows Form in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a method, where I call a new Windows Form in Class A. And in the new Form, I use a Dropdown menu and store the selected Item from the Dropdown in a variable, called `selectedItem`.Now I have to access this `selectedItem` in Class A. I use the following code.

```
public class A
{
    public method callingmethod()
    {
        ExceptionForm expform = new ExceptionForm();
        expform.Show();
        string newexp = expobj.selectedexception;
    }
}
```

And my code in New Form,

```
public partial class ExceptionForm : Form
{
    public string selectedexception = string.Empty;
    private void btnExpSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        selectedexception = this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem);
        this.Close();
        return;
    }
}
```

Now After clicking on Submit button, I get the correct value in `selectedItem`, But I could not pass it to Class A. How to retun to Class A?

Comment: Have you tried making selectedException a property with a get / set accessor?

Comment: Use `expform.ShowDialog()` instead of Show otherwise the code will continue to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok with posting `ExceptionForm` over parent form by disabling it, go for `ShowDialog`. But, if you do not wish to disable parent for and continue popping `ExceptionForm` as a new and independent window, try eventing back to parent form. Here I show an example on how to do so:

```
public partial class ExceptionForm : Form
{
    public delegate void SelectValueDelegate(string option);
    public event SelectValueDelegate ValueSelected;

    private void btnExpSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();

        if (this.ValueSelected!= null)
        {
            this.ValueSelected(this.comboBox1.GetItemText(this.comboBox1.SelectedItem));
        }

        return;
    }
}
```

And in calling class:

```
public class A
{
    public method callingmethod()
    {
        ExceptionForm expform = new ExceptionForm();
        expform.ValueSelected += ExceptionForm_ValueSelected;
        expform.Show();
    }

    private void ExceptionForm_ValueSelected(string option)
    {
        string newexp = option;
        // Do whatever you wanted to do next!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `ShowDialog()` method.

```
expform.ShowDialog();
string newexp = expobj.selectedexception;
```